# Searching a list of items from tkinter listbox in a mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, ttk

I am a programming beginner and am working on a program that diagnoses your ailment based on the symptoms that you have selected and recommends a certain medication. I have made a mysql database that contains a table known as 'ailments' which stores the name, cause, medication and symptoms of the ailment(symptom1, symptom2..... symptom n).

```
CREATE TABLE ailments(
  -> id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  -> name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  -> cause VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  -> medication VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  -> symptom1 VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  -> symptom2 VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  -> symptom3 VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  -> symptom4 VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  -> symptom5 VARCHAR(30) NULL);
```

I have also made two tkinter listboxes, one containing various symptoms and the other containing the symptoms that the user will have selected through the 'Add' button.

What I want is when the user presses the 'Diagnose' button in the GUI, it will display the name of the ailment based on the symptoms that the user will have selected, after querying the 'ailments' table, its cause and it's medication. The problem is that I don't know how to query the 'ailments' table using the symptoms that the user has selected in the listbox.

The query should focus on the symptoms columns(symptom1, symptom2..... symptom n) and for the name, cause and medication of the ailment to be displayed, not every symptom from the symptoms columns(symptom1, symptom2..... symptom n) must be present in the symptoms that the user will have selected. Let's say it should display the name, cause and medication of the ailment after majority of the selected symptoms match the symptoms of the ailment in the 'ailments' table.

I have found very little help from the web.

The code below only prints the selected symptoms. I hope someone understands me. Any help will be valued and also any suggestion to build my program in a more convenient way (but still use mysql and python) will be accepted.

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('425x300')


def add_symptom():
    y = symptoms.get(ACTIVE)
    selected_symptoms.insert(END, y)


def remove_symptom():
    selected_symptoms.delete(ACTIVE)


def diagnosis_validation():
    if selected_symptoms.size() < 5:
        print('Insufficient symptoms for diagnosis')
    else:
        diagnose()


def diagnose():
    for a in selected_symptoms.get(0, END):
        print(a)

label1 = Label(root, text='Symptoms')
label1.place(x=5, y=5)

i = ['Fever', 'Headache', 'Vomiting', 'Weakness', 'Blood in urine', 'Joint pains', 'Stomachache',
 'Heavy sweating']

symptoms = Listbox(root)
symptoms.place(x=5, y=30,
           width=150, height=200)
for x in i:
    symptoms.insert(END, x)

scrollb1 = Scrollbar(root, command=symptoms.yview)
scrollb1.place(x=154, y=31, height=200)

symptoms.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollb1.set)

label2 = Label(root, text='Selected symptoms')
label2.place(x=255, y=5)

selected_symptoms = Listbox(root)
selected_symptoms.place(x=255, y=30, width=150, height=200)

scrollb2 = Scrollbar(root, command=selected_symptoms.yview)
scrollb2.place(x=404, y=31, height=200)

selected_symptoms.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollb2.set)

add_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Add',
                    command=add_symptom)
add_button.place(x=175, y=30)

remove_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Remove',
                       command=remove_symptom)
remove_button.place(x=175, y=70)

diagnose_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Diagnose',
                         command=diagnosis_validation)
diagnose_button.place(x=175, y=205)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, it depends how you actually want to select the ailments, theres one simple way which just depends on a threshold x, like if symptoms > 2 then recommend this ailment but this is not the right way. Other way is to give each symptom a weight and decide the threshold according to the total weight.....

Comment: Could you please describe a sample working code because as I said, am a beginner